# How to pass object to Inertia.js page to be displayed

Tags: vuejs2, laravel-8, inertiajs

**What I Want**

pass an object to the Vue component being rendered to display the object's info

**What I'm Doing**

*Page Controller*

```
<?php

namespace App\HTTP\Controllers;

use Inertia\Inertia;
use App\Http\Controllers\Controller;
use App\Models\project;

class ProjectController extends Controller {
     
    public function project(project $project){
        return Inertia::render('Projects/ProjectPage', [
            'project' => [
                'id' => $project->id,
                'projectImage' => $project->projectImage,
                'projectText' => $project->projectText,
            ]
        ]);
    }
}
```

*Route To Page*

```
<div v-for="project in this.$page.props.projects" :key="project.id" class="flex flex-row py-2 hover:shadow-lg">
    <inertia-link :href="route('projectPage', project.id)" > <ProjectTile :project="project" class="py-4"/> </inertia-link>
</div>
```

*Page Rendering Object*

```
<template>
    <!-- Root div -->
    <div>
        This is the project page
        {{project.projectName}}
    </div>
    <!-- End Root div -->
</template>

<script>
export default {
    props: {
        project: Object,
    }
}
</script>
```

*Route In routes/web.php*

```
Route::get('projects/{projectid}', [ProjectController::class, 'project'])->name('projectPage');
```

**What This Results In**

```
page:Object
    props:Object
        errors:Object (empty)
        project:Object
            id:null
            projectImage:null
            projectText:null
```

Comment: Did you verify that you are in fact getting the correct value in your controller? If you place `dd($project->id);` as the first line in your `project()` method in your controller do you get the right value?

Comment: That was not the main issue, which has been pointed out on the laracasts forum, thank you for your assistance @Andrew

Answer (score 0, accepted):

param passed to controller here

```
public function project(project $project){ ... }
```

must be the same as what is referenced in route here

```
Route::get('projects/{projectid}')...
```

solution:

```
public function project(project $projectid){ ... }
```

Comment: credit to the user over at laracasts.com who gave the answer here https://laracasts.com/discuss/channels/vue/how-to-pass-object-to-vue-component-to-be-displayed